# Publishing page : insert link

Tags: 2010, publishing-page

I am trying to add link in sharepoint 2010 publishing page. When I am trying to add perticular link and saving the page, Link is getting removed from it. Able to add all other link. But not able to add that perticular one. Can anyone suggest , what should be the cause of it?
I am adding URl in URL tab and saving the page. URL tab is getting empty.
[image: this is how I am adding link]

[image]

Comment: That link work perfect on other pages.

Comment: what type of page is that, is that conflicting with any other page or bookmark.

Comment: anything special with that page?

Comment: This is publishing page. There is noting special about that page. It is not even conflicitng with any other page or bookmark I am finding this behaviour little strange. This is only happening for that link on that page only. Other links are working perfectly on that page and This link is working perfectly on other pages.

Comment: Hi Waqas, , 
 I can see some special characters in the link   . Is that causing the issue. Because link is working now, when I removed that special character "-"

Comment: Most probably, it is...is this link from SharePoint site or non sharepoint site? what special characters are? usually sharepoint doesnot allow special characters in the url.

Comment: It was sharepoint link only, document inside document library. I am not even able to add that special character here. I will add screenshot to my question for you. Thsese special characters are in the the document name.